# index of a vector field induced by diffeomorphism between surfaces is same as the index of the original vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Definition. Let $p$ be an isolated singular point of a tangent field V on an oriented
regular surface $S$. Let $R\subset S$ be a polygonal region whose interior
contains $p$, with no other singular points in its interior or boundary.
Let $\gamma : [a, b] \to S$ be a positively oriented parametrization of $\partial R$. Let
$\sigma : U \subset \Bbb R^2 → S$ be a surface patch covering $R$ that is compatible with
the orientation. For $t ∈ [a, b]$, let $σ_u(t)$ and $V (t)$ denote the values of
$σ_u$ and $V$ at $γ(t)$. Let $ϕ : [a, b] → \Bbb R$ be a continuous function such
that for all $t ∈ [a, b], ϕ(t)$ equals the angle from $σ_u(t)$ to $V (t)$; more
precisely, $V (t)$ is a positive scalar multiple of the counterclockwise
rotation of $σ_u(t)$ by the angle $ϕ(t)$. The $\textbf{index}$ of $V$ at $p$ is defined as $I(p) = \frac{1}{2\pi}(\varphi(b)-\varphi(a))$.

I want to prove the following:

> Let $f:S\to\tilde{S}$ be a diffeomorphism between smooth surfaces. Let $V$ be a vector field on $S$. Let $\tilde{V}$ be the induced vector field on $\tilde{S}$, whose value at $f(p)$ equals $df_p(V(p))$ for each $p\in S$. Let $p$ be an isolated singular point of $V$. Prove that the index of $V$ at $p$ equals the index of $\tilde{V}$ at $f(p)$.

This is an exercise in (Undergraduate) Differential geometry of curves and surfaces by Tapp.

At $\gamma(t)$, we denote $\sigma_u(t)$ and $V(t)$ as in the definition. Then I think that on $\tilde{S}$, it changes to $df_{\sigma(t)}(\sigma_u(t))$ and $df_{\sigma(t)}(V(t))$ and $\varphi$ to $df_{\sigma(t)}(\varphi(t))...?$ I don't know how to get further. Could you help?